# How to check class randomized object result with its derived class constraint

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Let say I have these two classes:

```
class random_packet extends uvm_sequence_item;
    rand int cmd;
    ...
endclass
```

and its extension:

```
class good_packet extends random_packet;
    constraint good_constr {
    cmd inside {0,1,2};
    }
    ...
endclass
```

(Here I am not going to create `good_packet` object, but I just want to use its constraint as a reference)
Then I instantiate random_packet object and randomize it:

```
random_packet pkt;
pkt = random_packet::type_id::create("pkt");
pkt.randomize();
```

My question: Is there a simpler way by utilizing its derived class `good_packet`'s constraint to check whether the resultant `pkt.cmd` fall in category of `good_packet` constraint ? 
It would be better than writing redundant codes like:

```
if (pkt.cmd == 0 || pkt.cmd == 1 || pkt.cmd == 2) $display("good");
else $display("bad");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could copy the contents of `pkt` into a new packet of type `good_packet` and then check if the constraint holds.

First, you'll need a function that can update the fields of a `good_packet` based on the fields of a `random_packet`:

```
class random_packet extends uvm_sequence_item;
  // ...

  virtual function void update(random_packet source);
    this.cmd = source.cmd;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Using this function, you can update the fields of a `good_packet` that you've created earlier:

```
// ... randomization of 'pkt' happened earlier

good_packet g_pkt = new();
g_pkt.update(pkt);
```

Now that `g_pkt` contains the same values as `pkt`, you can use the inline constraint checker construct to check if the constraints defined in the `good_packet` class hold:

```
if (g_pkt.randomize(null))
  $display("good");
else
  $display("bad");
```

The call to `randomize(null)` won't actually randomize anything inside `g_pkt` (it's kind of like setting every field to `rand_mode(0)`).

You can find more info on this construct in section **18.11.1 In-line constraint checker** of the [IEEE 1800-2012 standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Comment: Even though we set the constraint mode to 0, does the the call to randomize() still try to solve the constraints ?

Comment: @VineethVS We don't set `constraint_mode` to 0. I said it's like setting `rand_mode` to 0. The solver will take the values that are already set and check if they match **all** of the constraints that are enabled.

Comment: @Tudor This is exactly what I want, Thanks! randomize(null) is to force the randomize() method to behave as a checker.

Comment: @Tudor Sorry that was a typo. I understand what you were saying about `constraint_mode`. What I meant to ask was that if we set the `rand_mode` to 0 and then do `randomize(null)` ;do the solver try to solve the constraints. Anyways I just tried and figured out the difference. Thanks for the reply.